# DEVISE: Custom redirect when no users are logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Currently devise is always redirecting me to `/users/sign_in` when no session is available. I want to change that redirect to a custom route, for example `/home`. Is this possible?

Comment: So somewhere, likely in `application_controller.rb`, it sounds like you have you have `authenticate_user!` in there.  In place of that put in a before_action method that redirects to that page if `user_signed_in?` returns false.  If you need an actual code example can you share you application_controller.rb file code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes .It is possible.
Change the line in application.html.erb file in app/view/layouts
from

```
     <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Login", your_custom_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
```